# How to check if a string is not consist of any characters but those specified

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to ensure that a string doesn't have anything but "A" or "B" or "C".

I thought it would be something like:

```
var str = "CBA";

str.match("[ABC]+");
```

but this is true also for "CBG". How can I make sure outside of "ABC" not to be allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the anchors(`^ $`). Here it is:

```
 str.match("^[ABC]+$");
```

These anchors will force the regex to match with whole string. Whereas without those, it matches with the part of the string.